# can expect be told not to timeout without explicitly setting a huge constant value?

Tags: expect

I've set the timeout to a stupid high number. Is there a better way to tell the script not to time out?

```
#!/usr/bin/expect
spawn telnet 10.10.10.10
set timeout 200000000
expect "login"
send "user\r"
expect "Password:"
send "password\r"
send "./run/this.sh\r"
```

Comment: At least with the `expect` command itself, you can use -1 to indicate an infinite timeout; I assume you can use it for the global variable as well.

Comment: expect is not part of bash or based on bash (the language it's an extension to is TCL), and this question doesn't use bash at all. There's no justification for having bash as part of the title or question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Set the `timeout` value to `-1`

```
set timeout -1
```

An excerpt from the `expect`, [`man page`](http://www.tcl.tk/man/expect5.31/expect.1.html)

> If no timeout keyword is used, an implicit null action is executed upon timeout. *The default timeout period is 10 seconds* but may be set, for example to 30, by the command "set timeout 30". *An infinite timeout may be designated by the value -1*.